# Using PHP can we search for a filename pattern in a directory

Tags: php, file, file-io

Am having a folder with millions of files in the server

File name will be `LMN20110305.txt`  pattern.

If i am trying to search for files in april only am now reading directory

getting the filename and using substring am checking it is greater than or less than of

`20110401` and `20110430`

In this case it will read entire directory and it is taking so many hours.
Am thinking about checking create date also.

How will be the performance of `glob` — Find pathnames matching a pattern

Any one have any better suggestion?

Silly doubt! Is it possible to find the files without searching entire directory?

Comment: I suppose it's too late to start using subdirectories...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) will perform fine. It's in the standard library for a reason, use it!

It's my understanding that `glob()` maps almost directly to the `glob()` function in your system's C library, meaning that it will most likely be more efficient than anything you roll your own. The only limit is memory: if you run out of memory, you'll either need to give PHP more memory or reorganize.

If you run in to memory problems, how about organizing your files a little better? A million files in one folder is way too many. Organize them somehow. If your files are dated, try organizing them by year (and then maybe month), along the lines of:

```
basedir/
|---/2011
|---/2010
etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for answer...But please tell something about this page ...Don't use glob() if you try to list files in a directory where very much files are stored (>100.000). You get an "Allowed memory size of XYZ bytes exhausted ..." error.
You may try to increase the memory_limit variable in php.ini. Mine has 128MB set and the script will still reach this limit while glob()ing over 500.000 files. http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: @zod that's a user comment. The user comments on php.net are, well, iffy... There's no set limit for how many files you can glob, but if you have a million files, you'll run out of memory. You're going to need to either allocate more memory or reorganize your files.

Comment: @zod if you hit the memory limit, try using `GLOB_NOSORT` as second parameter to `glob()`.  If you still hit this memory limit, do the `opendir()`, `readdir()` loop, `closedir()` as stated by the comment you are referring in the glob manual page.

Answer (score 1):

That's more a file system issue than PHP.  PHP has no special methods for reading the directory other than via the usual system calls.  You need to alter the storage pattern, some sort of tree structure appropriate to the distribution of data coming in.